# Django reverse referrential integrity

Tags: python, mysql, django, rdbms

First, excuse the title, I have searched for hours but still can't find what the technical name is for this question. But, supposing you have a many-to-one relationship like books and chapters:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Chapter(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Referrential integrity would require that every chapter points to a book that exists. I require also the opposite, that every book is pointed to by at least one Chapter. Two immediate implications are that:
- Whenever a book is created, at least one chapter must simultaneously be created.
- Whenever the last remaining chapter of a book is deleted, the book must be deleted automatically.
My questions are:
- What is actually the correct term to describe this constraint?
- Is it possible in any RDBMS to enforce this constraint in the DB? Or does it have to be created at the application level.
- In Django, how could I create this constraint?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to add a constraint on db level, but there a couple of ways to tackle this on django level. You can, for instance, create a view with atomic transactions to make sure that the book is not created if the chapter is not created just after. For deletions, you could use a post_save signal to delete the book. Let me know if you want me to compose a proper answer with this approach.

Comment: Thanks @Stargazer. Don't worry I think I could figure out how to use the signals then.